# Как указать компилятору заполнить статический массив одинаковыми ненулевыми значениями?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86-64

Елементарный способ: произвести заполнение массива при инициализации. Но массив статический и уже занимает место в образе. Нужно каким-то образом указать компилятору заполнить область массива конкретным значением. 
Код `static int arr[5]={1}` заполняется как {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, а нужно {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

`__attribute__((fillupper(1)))` игнорируется gcc.

Массив неконстантный. Массив с 5 элементами - пример. Нужно заполнить массив в 4096 элементов.
Использование возможностей STL сильно ограничены, включая производные. Они все имеют элементарное решение, указанное в первом предложении.

Доработка ответа:

```
template <typename type, type v>
struct IArray {
  type val = v;
  IArray& operator=(type n){
    val=n;
    return *this;
  }
  IArray& operator|=(type n){
    val|=n;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

И необходимо дописать/изменить операторы для нужных Вам преобразований.

Comment: *Код static int arr[5]={1} заполняется как {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, а нужно {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}* Стесняюсь даже спросить: а `static int arr[5]={1, 1, 1, 1, 1}` что, не срабатывает?

Comment: @Akina, это был пример. Предлагаете заполнить массив 4096-тью единицами?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать контейнер, vector или array, например?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, разработка ОС. Стандарты STL доступны только как синтаксические возможности компилятора.

Comment: boost.preprocessor доступна, или отметена вместе с контейнерами?

Comment: @Chorkov, да. Почти чистый С.

Comment: *Предлагаете заполнить массив 4096-тью единицами?* А Вам, я извиняюсь, не пофиг? один раз всего-то и сделать (причём можно и программно такой файл создать, а не руками 4к раз по единице шлёпать).

Comment: А что за аттрибут такой `fillupper`?

Comment: @Akina, один раз можно и перфокарты продырявить.

Comment: @AnT, http://electronix.ru/forum/index.php?act=attach&id=34470&type=post страница 4

Comment: @Adokenai, доработка Ваша не будет работать с double типом, например.

Comment: @isnullxbh, не могу спорить. Не проверял. Для более сложных типов возможно придётся переопределять ещё операторы. В любом случае, изначальный вариант решает вопрос, но не решает сопутствующих проблем вроде обработки значений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

template <int v>
struct Int {
    int val = v;
};

int main() {
    Int<10> arr[1024];
    std::cout << arr[10].val << std::endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6-BEPi

Comment: Всё гениальное - просто. Работает.

Answer (score 4):

Не бейте меня. Нашёл только `asm` способ.

```
//> g++ -std=c++11 memset.cpp
#include<iostream>

asm(  
"   .globl  s2\n"
"   .data\n"
"   .align 32\n"
"   .type   s2, @object\n"
"   .size   s2, 16384\n"
"s2: .fill 4096,4,777\n"
);

extern "C" { extern int s2[4096]; };

int main(){
  for(size_t j = 4096+1;j>0;){--j; std::cout<<"s2["<<j<<"]="<<s2[j]<<" ";}
  std::cout<<"s2["<<-1<<"]="<<s2[-1]<<std::endl;  }
```

***Неправильный ответ:***
Используйте **memset** это очень просто. Пример:

```
//> g++ -std=c++11 -S memset.cpp
#include <string.h>
int main(){
  int m[4096]{};
  int n[4096];
  memset(n,1,4096);
  }
```

Результатом будет код:

```
subq    $32768, %rsp
leaq    -32768(%rbp), %rax
movl    $16384, %edx
movl    $0, %esi
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    memset
leaq    -16384(%rbp), %rax
movl    $4096, %edx
movl    $1, %esi
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    memset
```

Как видите, никакой разницы , только 0 и 1 .

Comment: Кажется, нужно упомянуть об отключении оптимизаций - при включенной оптимизации компилятор может "выкинуть" этот код.

Comment: memset использовать - это элементарный способ, что в первом предложении дополнения к вопросу указано.

Comment: Это каким это образом вы собираетесь так использовать `memset`? Функция `memset` выставляет значения *байтов*. Массив `int` вы с ее помощью единицами не заполните. "Никакой разницы", говорите? А на размеры обратили внимание?

Comment: @AnT, с некоторыми изменениями memset можно использовать. Но это тоже самое, что использовать цикл при инициализации. То есть это не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @Adokenai, ```с некоторыми изменениями memset можно использовать``` - можете рассказать, с какими?

Comment: Не спорьте, облажался по поводу байта с интами.

Comment: @isnullxbh, указывать каждый 4/8 байт. В общем извращение.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, а мы и не спорим  :) Пока есть возможность узнать от более осведомленных людей что-то полезное - нужно эту возможность использовать.

Comment: Попробуйте тогда ассемблер из моего ответа

Comment: @AlexGlebe, немного допилил и заработало. В частности вызов функции s2 не нужен, а нужен extern "C" { extern int * s2; };

Answer (score 3):

GCC поддерживает нестандартный синтаксис

```
static int arr[4096] = { [0 ... 4095] = 1 };
```

Но это расширение возможностей designated initializers, т.е. это С, а не С++.

То есть можно, если устроит такой вариант, сделать в С++ проекте отдельный С-файл с

```
int arr[4096] = { [0 ... 4095] = 1 };
```

а в С++ коде уже добавить

```
extern "C" int arr[4096];
```

если вы готовы пожертвовать `static`.

Comment: Всё верно. Для С++ не работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/sarr conv=swab count=4096
xxd -i /tmp/sarr | sed -e 's/0x00/0x01/g' > /tmp/parr.h
```

P.S. :)

UPD:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, size_t N, T def_val>
class ct_array {
public:
    constexpr explicit ct_array();

public:
    const T& operator[](size_t idx) const;

protected:
    T m_data[N];
};

template <typename T, size_t N, T def_val>
constexpr ct_array<T, N, def_val>::ct_array()
    : m_data()
{
    for (T *el = m_data; el != m_data + N; ++el)
        *el = def_val;
}

template <typename T, size_t N, T def_val>
const T& ct_array<T, N, def_val>::operator[](size_t idx) const {
    return m_data[idx];
}

template <typename T, size_t N, T def_val>
constexpr decltype(auto) make_ct_array() {
    return ct_array<T, N, def_val>();
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto arr = make_ct_array<int, 1024, 0x01>();
    std::cout << arr[10] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

UPD2:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, size_t N>
class ct_array {
public:
    constexpr explicit ct_array(T def);

public:
    const T& operator[](size_t idx) const;

protected:
    T m_data[N];
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr ct_array<T, N>::ct_array(T def)
    : m_data()
{
    for (T *el = m_data; el != m_data + N; ++el)
        *el = def;
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
const T& ct_array<T, N>::operator[](size_t idx) const {
    return m_data[idx];
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr decltype(auto) make_ct_array(T def) {
    return ct_array<T, N>(def);
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto arr = make_ct_array<double, 1024>(3.14);
    std::cout << arr[10] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Шутка засчитана.

Comment: @Adokenai, спасибо! :)

Comment: Из очереди проверок: несёт в себе признаки ответа, поэтому с формальной точки зрения "выглядит нормально". Является ответом неправильным, шутливым, поэтому не ориентируйтесь на него. Минусануть рука не подымается.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать функцию

```
template <class T>
void f(T a[], size_t s, const T& n)
{
     for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i)
         a[i] = n;
}
```

Тогда

```
const int n = 4096;
int arr[n];
f(arr, n, 1);
```

после ее вызова вы получите желаемый результат

Или же воспользоваться стандартным альгоритмом

```
const int n = 4096;
int arr[n];
std::fill(arr, arr + n, 1);
```

Comment: Чем это отличается от элементарного способа, что описан в дополнении в первом предложении?

Comment: Да, я невнимательно прочитал, но иначе никак, и это еще одна причина воспользоваться стандартными контейнерами

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, а constexpr-функции могут в качестве возвращаемого типа иметь массив скаляров?

Comment: @snullxbh, а где вы видели, что функция возвращала что либо?